# Chat search broken in mobile Safari

Tags: bug, chat, search, mobile-safari

Using Mobile Safari in iOS 8.4, and the full-site chat interface,<sup>1</sup> if I type something in the search field and tap <kbd>Search</kbd> on the virtual keyboard, nothing happens.  The virtual keyboard retracts, the search field is cleared, no search results are displayed, and I'm still on the same chat screen.

On the other hand, if I go to <kbd>Full Transcript</kbd> first and try searching from there, it works.

---

<sup>1</sup> Can't use the dumbed-down mobile interface, since it lacks a search feature.